# Can't access the mysqli_result Object of an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hi I have a problem with this method and it's driving me crazy.The query below should return one field from the database, an id where the filename is matched. Only one value should be returned. When I run the query I get an SQL object returned which looks fine:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

However I cannot access the above query object no matter what way I try or at least I'm getting no value out of it. I did the exact same to get the package id and it works perfectly.

I used $row = $result_package_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
to get the package_id and I tried that for the module_id but it didn't work. Tried the mysqli_fetch_array and it doesn't work either. At a loss of what to do next can anyone help?

**ADDED getPackageId method and if statement where the two methods are called. Every time a query is successful the id and package id are retrieved and a new object is created with the two values.**

```
function getId($fileName){
    $con = connect();
    if (!$con) {
        trigger_error(mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $yModuleId = 0;
    $sql_filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fileName);
    $query_module_id = "SELECT id FROM y_module WHERE fileName='" . $sql_filename . "'";
    $result_module_id = mysqli_query($con, $query_module_id);
    while($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_module_id)){
        $yModuleId = $row_model['id'];
        return $yModuleId;
    }
}


function getYPackageId($package_name){
    $con = connect();
    if (!$con) {

        trigger_error(mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $sql_packageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $package_name);

    $query_package_id = "SELECT id FROM y_package WHERE name='" . $package_name . "'";
    $result_package_id = mysqli_query($con, $query_package_id)  or die("__LINE__ : " . mysqli_error($con));

    while($row_package = mysqli_fetch_array($result_package_id)){
        $yPackageId = $row_package['id'];
        print_r($yPackageId);
        print_r("</br>");
        print_r("</br>");
        return $yPackageId;
    };
}

if($result_model && $result_package && $result_model_package) {
        $yModuleId = getId($fileName);
        $yPackageId = getYPackageId($package_name);
        $yIdObject = new YIds($yModuleId, $yaPackageId);
        $yIdObjects [] = $yIdObject;
        mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT");
        $message = array("success", "[SUCCESS]", "Model published successfully.",$module_id);
}
```

Comment: Sql server is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Ok bit of an update the printout for getting the package id is    mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) and the printout for module_id is      mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) I've no idea why this is happening but num_rows is 0 for module_id and for package_id its 1. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this it's pretty urgent and I'm not getting anywhere with it!

Comment: I noticed when I run and do the printout that there should be 5 package_ids but there is only 4 printed, the first query seems to contain the same values in the object as module_id

Comment: ` print_r("</br>");` This is bad syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $saved[] = $row;
}
```

but I think from your code displayed a more important issue is that you seem to be mixing procedural and object orientated SQL querying.

So:

- 1) Rewrite yourcode to use objects, your usage of `mysqli_` functions only returns arrays.
- 2) or alternatively, use the current code as an array because that's what it is, not an object.

**Procedural**

```
function getId($fileName){
     //this does nothing. Unless this is a custom function?
     //$con = connect();
    // should be:
    $con = mysqli_connect(details,...);
    if (!$con) {
        trigger_error(mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR); //?
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    //$yModuleId = 0; //unneeded.
    $sql_filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fileName);
    $query_module_id = "SELECT id FROM y_module WHERE fileName='" . $sql_filename . "'";
    //add an error feedback for debugging:
    $result_module_id = mysqli_query($con, $query_module_id) or die("__LINE__.":".mysqli_error($con));
    while($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_module_id)){
        $yModuleId = $row_model['id'];
        return $yModuleId;
    }
}
```

**Object Orientated:**

```
 $query_module_id = "SELECT id FROM y_module WHERE fileName='?'";
$con = new mysqli($details,...);
$thisQuery = $con->prepare($query_module_id);
$thisQuery->bind_param("s",$sql_filename);
$thisQuery->execute();
 while ($row = $thisQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
       $saved[] = $row;
    }
$thisQuery->close();
```

From this the `$saved` variable will be an array of results.

---

**Additional notes:**

- You are using MySQL COMMIT near the bottom of your code and this is for *transactions* but you have not shown you've  setup or begun any MySQL transactions.
- You have a `return` inside a `while` statement in `getYPackageId` which means that the while wil only ever run once because as soon as it reaches the return it will do just that. Bad format.
- Remove the semi-colon after the closing bracket of the `while` statement. This is bad syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for trying to help really appreciate it. The code should be procedural so I used your code from the procedural example. The $con = connect(); is fine by the way its a custom function to connect to the database. However I'm still getting the same problem. The getId and getPackageId run one after another in a loop 5 times. This is the printout I get.                                                                                        157

157

157

157 The 157 is the result of printing out the result of the getPackageId method.

Comment: In the getId method it doesn't even enter the while loop and no printout occurs. The getPackageId should also be printed five times not four, so its having the same problem as getId the first time it runs. I have a load of sql queries just like it that run perfect in the same file can't figure out why these two wont work.

Comment: You are not going to get an object from a procedural SL query

Comment: Can you show *all* your **relevant** code, as I don't know what `getPackageId` is etc. Please edit your original question @olliejjc16

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "You are not going to get an object from a procedural SL query".  I get a mysqli_object returned when my query is run is that not an object? I've added the extra code anyways, I know in the if statement I am using a class and creating objects but the code should be mainly procedural, there's just some places I couldn't get around it without creating class objects.

Comment: @olliejjc16 you need to clarify your details some more. What is the variable name of the object you display in you question? Please show this in your question (another edit!). My impression is that you're getting confusions from using both Procedural and OOP interfaces with the SQL database. That's just my impression. Also, can you turn on [PHP error logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) on your page which will also help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and I feel like such an idiot! The problem was here

```
if($result_model && $result_package && $result_model_package) {
    $yModuleId = getId($fileName);
    $yPackageId = getYPackageId($package_name);
    $yIdObject = new YIds($yModuleId, $yaPackageId);
    $yIdObjects [] = $yIdObject;
    mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT");
    $message = array("success", "[SUCCESS]", "Model published successfully.",$module_id);
}
```

I was running the commit after I was trying to get the id and package_id from the database that's why I wasn't getting any results. I changed it to this:

```
if($result_model && $result_package && $result_model_package) {
     mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT");
     $yModuleId = getId($fileName);
    $yPackageId = getYPackageId($package_name);
    $yIdObject = new YIds($yModuleId, $yaPackageId);
    $yIdObjects [] = $yIdObject;

    $message = array("success", "[SUCCESS]", "Model published successfully.",$module_id);
}
```

It worked perfectly. This is how the getId() method looked when I got it working

```
function getId($moduleName, $moduleRevision){


       $con = connect();
       if (!$con) {
           trigger_error(mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
       }
       $sql_moduleName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $moduleName);
       $sql_moduleRevision = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $moduleRevision);

       $query_module_id = "SELECT id, module_name, module_revision FROM y_module";
       $result_module_id = mysqli_query($con, $query_module_id);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_module_id)){
          if($row['module_name'] === $moduleName && $row['module_revision'] == $moduleRevision){
          return $row['id'];
          }
       }
}
```

Thanks to Martin for all the help and the advice much appreciated! Hope this can help someone by not making the same stupid mistake as me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. feel free to plus one my attempt at solving your problem :-D .